# How to assign multiple attributes at once to an object in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, methods

I have an object `Foo` and want to assign multiple attributes to it at once, similar to `assign_attributes` in Rails:

```
class Foo
    attr_accessor :a, :b, :c
end

f = Foo.new
my_hash = {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "baz"}
f.assign_attributes(my_hash)
```

The above does not work except if the class is an ActiveRecord Model in Rails. Is there any way to do it in Ruby?

Comment: BTW, most of Rails is implemented in Ruby, so you can always have a look at [its source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb#L28). (although some of it is quite complex and might be hard to understand)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement the mass-assignment method yourself.

One option is to set the corresponding instance variables via [`instance_variable_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Object.html#instance_variable_set-method):

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c

  def assign_attributes(attrs)
    attrs.each_pair do |attr, value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{attr}", value)
    end
  end
end
```

Note that this will by-pass any custom setters. As said in the docs:

> This may circumvent the encapsulation intended by the author of the class, so it should be used with care.

Another way is to dynamically invoke the setters via [`public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Object.html#public_send-method):

```
  def assign_attributes(attrs)
    attrs.each_pair do |attr, value|
      public_send("#{attr}=", value)
    end
  end
```

This is equivalent to setting each single attribute sequentially. If a setter has been (re)defined to include constraints and controls on the value being set, the latter approach respects that.

It also raises an exception if you try to set undefined attributes: (because the corresponding setter doesn't exist)

```
f = Foo.new
f.assign_attributes(d: 'qux')
#=> NoMehodError: undefined method `d=' for #<Foo:0x00007fbb76038430>
```

In addition, you might want to ensure that the passed argument is indeed a hash and maybe raise a custom exception if the provided attributes are invalid / unknown.

Comment: I would argue that the later is a much better implementation because the instance variable assignment option lacks the structured control provided by `attr_accessor` e.g. `f.assign_attributes(('a'..'zzz').then {|a| a.zip(a)}.to_h)`

Comment: Hashes can be ensured by convention using `to_h` and `to_hash`.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira probably depends on your use case, but I'd rather use `is_a?(Hash)` or `respond_to?(:each_pair)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `assign_attributes` is an instance method of `ActiveRecord`

You have to define your `assign_attributes` method if not using `ActiveRecord`

```
def assign_attributes(attrs_hash)
  attrs_hash.each do |k, v|
    self.instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
  end
end
```